CUDA, PyTorch and YOLO Integration problem
I installed Python 3.11 and then recompiled OpenCV with CUDA. I was working on YOLO with CUDA as well, but now when I run PyTorch 12.4 with CUDA, I’m getting this error for YOLO:

could not load symbol cudnngetlibconfig. error code 127.” Later, when
I tried running my YOLO code with another PyTorch version, I got this
error instead: “OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure
could not be found. Error loading
‘C:\Users\MikailAkdeniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\cufftw64_11.dll’
or one of its dependencies.

What should I do?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\MikailAkdeniz\OneDrive - MİS ENDÜSTRİYEL ÇÖZÜMLER OTOMASYON SANAYİ VE DIŞ TİCARET ANONİM ŞİRKET\Masaüstü\heatmap\heatmapp.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ultralytics import YOLO
  File "C:\Users\MikailAkdeniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ultralytics.data.explorer.explorer import Explorer
  File "C:\Users\MikailAkdeniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .base import BaseDataset
  File "C:\Users\MikailAkdeniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\data\base.py", line 15, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data import Dataset
  File "C:\Users\MikailAkdeniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 245, in <module>
    _load_dll_libraries()
  File "C:\Users\MikailAkdeniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 228, in _load_dll_libraries
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 127] Belirtilen yordam bulunamadı. Error loading "C:\Users\MikailAkdeniz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\cufftw64_11.dll" or one of its dependencies.  


crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/cuda-pytorch-and-yolo-integration-problem/18082

Downgrade Python to version 3.8, which is known to work well with PyTorch and CUDA.
